# (In Lean), why cannot structural recursion on propositions be used?

Tags: lean4, inductive-type, propositions

**Update**: this has been fixed and the fix is available in the [latest nightly release](https://github.com/leanprover/lean4-nightly/releases/tag/nightly-2022-10-08) of Lean 4.

In Lean 4, structural recursion on functions on types is no issue.

```
inductive F where
  | nil (n: Nat)
  | fn (f: Nat → F)

def inc: F → F
  | F.nil n => F.nil (n+1)
  | F.fn f => F.fn fun n => inc (f n)
```

However, the same cannot be said of functions to
propositions. In the above, when `inductive F` is replaced
by `inductive F: Prop`, the function `inc` starts throwing
this error:

```
fail to show termination for
  inc
with errors
structural recursion cannot be used
```

**Question**: Why is this the case? Is this a type theory
thing, or a Lean thing?

---

I thought of one potential answer, but I have no idea
whether it's right. Here's my guess:

Propositions are impredicative, that means they
can quantify over themselves, and that means that
unlike for types, function application on propositions
is not necessarily a structurally decreasing operation.
Members of inductive propositions aren't necessarily
structurally smaller. (In other words, the `Prop` version
of `F` is not a W-type, but an [M-type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductive_type),
is that right?)

What I find puzzling about this is that even if it's
true, then "structurally-looking" recusion on
propositions stil seems well-defined to me, and also
perhaps I'm totally wrong.

Comment: Is [invImage](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib4_docs/Init/WF.html#invImage) what you are looking for?  You can just do
`def subtypeWellfounded {T: Type} (s: Set T) [wfr : WellFoundedRelation T] : WellFoundedRelation { t: T // t ∈ s } := invImage Subtype.val wfr`

Comment: Then for your `relOut` definition, we have `(relOut T s wfr.rel) = (@subtypeWellfounded T s wfr).rel` definitionally.

Comment: I think the meta answer here for your second question is that you shouldn't usually have to mess around with `Acc`.  There is enough already in the library to avoid it.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll definitely use that. I asked how I can prove termination of the function I already have for the sake of learning how to prove termination using ad-hoc well-founded relations instead of those that are defined on a concrete type, but I guess that really is a separate question, so I'll delete that part. (If anybody disagrees or already has an partly-written answer, feel free to undo my edit.)

Comment: This has nothing to do with M-types (which are coinductive types): here all your types are inductive ones. It is also not a type-theory thing: as far as I can tell, your definition makes sense on any inductive type, be it in `Prop` or in `Type` (and eg. Coq is perfectly happy with it). I would thus think the issue lies in the way Lean treats (encodes ?) propositional inductive types.

Comment: I found this on the [Lean Zulip](https://leanprover.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/270676-lean4/topic/Failed%20to%20show%20termination/near/240797249) from a few months ago "We have structural recursion on arbitrary arguments for types and soon for predicates. This doesn't cover mutually recursive definitions for now. And we don't have well-founded recursion yet."  I wonder if it is just not implemented yet.

Comment: Just in case, I added it as an issue on the Lean 4 github: https://github.com/leanprover/lean4/issues/1674

Comment: It's difficult to imagine what you would do with such a Prop. Because of proof irrelevance, `inc` is the same as `id` and the fancy definition is meaningless.

Comment: I discovered this by trying to recursively define an instance of Acc by recursively consuming another. You can see more in the question's history of edits.

Comment: Leo just fixed it.  See the issue I linked to above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR: There is no logical reason I see that Lean can't do this.  It just seems like it is not implemented (and possibly it will be implemented in the future as [this comment on Zulip](https://leanprover.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/270676-lean4/topic/Failed%20to%20show%20termination/near/240797249) suggests).  Nonetheless, you can directly construct this using induction (or the underlying `rec` operator).  Moreover, since Lean is proof-irrelevant, there is no logical reason to give a proof via recursion, and in my opinion induction is always a better choice.

---

[Mario's Carneiro's answer on Zulip](https://leanprover.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/270676-lean4/topic/Destructor.20of.20Inductive.20Types/near/294454003) from a month ago may give some light, so let me repeat it here (although I am not positive I understand it correctly):

Lean's equation compiler doesn't support direct structural recursion, which is paradoxical since it is the simplest kind of recursion.

Instead it currently supports the following two types of recursion:

- *bounded recursion* is like structural recursion except it also allows doing multiple layers of inductive constructors at once
- *well founded recursion* is where you recurse on a well founded type with a natural number measure function

Bounded recursion doesn't work for inductives in `Prop`, just inductive in `Type u`.  Well founded recursion will attempt to do recursion on a natural number measure (or "height").  It might work on your toy example, but it is not powerful enough to proof that say `Acc` is well-founded.

---

A better option when using recursion to prove a `Prop` is just to use induction instead.  In your toy example you could do:

```
inductive F : Prop where
  | nil (n: Nat)
  | fn (f: Nat → F)

theorem inc: F → F := by
  intro t 
  induction t with 
  | nil n => exact F.nil (n+1)
  | fn f f_ih => exact F.fn f_ih
```

Not only is this proof valid, but it is also a faithful representation of your recursive construction.  The induction hypothesis `f_ih : forall x : Nat, F` is the inductive equivalent of the recursive step `inc (f ...)` in your structural recursion. The induction hypothesis is assuming that `inc` holds true for all the outputs of `f: Nat -> F`.   (Notice both `f_ih` and `lambda n, inc (f n)` have type `Nat -> F`.)

Nonetheless, Lean is proof-irrelevant and the proof doesn't matter logically.  This is even more reason to avoid recursive proofs of `Prop`s, when induction is a better choice.

---

Digging deeper, we can even give a convincing argument that this is the correct way to translate your recursive proofs to induction.  If we print the inductive proof above we get:

```
theorem inc : F → F :=
fun t => F.rec (fun n => F.nil (n + 1)) (fun f ih => F.fn ih) t
```

Now, we can see that this exact definition when applied to the Type-valued `F` gives exactly the same result as your recursive formula:

```
inductive F where
  | nil (n: Nat)
  | fn (f: Nat → F)

def inc1: F → F
  | F.nil n => F.nil (n+1)
  | F.fn f => F.fn fun n => inc1 (f n)

def inc2 : F → F :=
fun t => F.rec (fun n => F.nil (n + 1)) (fun f ih => F.fn ih) t

-- check if they behave the same
variable (foo : Nat -> Nat -> Nat)
#reduce inc1 (F.fn (fun n => F.fn (fun m => F.nil (foo n m))))
-- F.fn fun n => F.fn fun n_1 => F.nil (Nat.succ (foo n n_1))
#reduce inc2 (F.fn (fun n => F.fn (fun m => F.nil (foo n m))))
-- F.fn fun n => F.fn fun n_1 => F.nil (Nat.succ (foo n n_1))

-- prove they are the same
theorem same_inc (t : F) : inc1 t = inc2 t := by
  induction t with
  | nil n => rfl
  | fn f ih => calc
    inc1 (F.fn f) = F.fn fun n => inc1 (f n) := rfl
    _             = F.fn fun n => inc2 (f n) := by simp [ih]
    _             = inc2 (F.fn f)            := rfl
```

---

Finally, it should be noted that structural recursion seems to already be working for simpler inductive definitions in `Prop`:

```
inductive F : Prop where
  | nil (n: Int)
  | fn (f: F)

def inc: F → F
  | F.nil n => F.nil (n+1)
  | F.fn f => F.fn (inc f)
```

Indeed, it seems that parameters of the form `(... -> F)` in the inductive definition are what gives Lean 4 trouble.

Comment: Personally, I think the most important piece of info is in your comment: "We have structural recursion on arbitrary arguments for types and *soon* for predicates.". So in Lean 4, bounded recursion doesn't *yet* work for inductives in Prop, but there is no fundamental reason it shouldn't, it just needs to get implemented in Lean, and eventually it will.

Comment: @JozefMikušinec I updated the answer accordingly, but personally, I think the most important piece of info is when I said: "just to use induction instead".  Indeed, since Lean is proof-irrelevant, I see no reason to ever need to use recursion to prove a proposition.  I've updated my answer with a specific recipe for translating your recursive definition (and others like it) into induction.